# Pass argument to perl file in debugger and set breakpoint in file executed by system

Tags: perl, debugging, system, eval

So I run a file in the perl debugger using perl -d file.pl. But then the file.pl is supposed to take arguments also. How do I supply arguments to the file.pl
One more question: file.pl has this line in it:

```
system("./file2.pl");
```

Is there a way to set a breakpoint in file2.pl if it is running as `system`? I have spent 7 days on perl debugger and I am not able to set a breakpoint at file2.pl Please help

EDIT: Got an awesome response from DVK to add DB::single=1. I tested that on some files and it worked. But I have more than a 100 files and if I do this manually, it will take me a lot of time. I use .perldb and use afterinit to typeahead all commands. I have put in place an algorithm which finds the line number of each file where the breakpoint needs to go. I just can't randomly (automatically using an executable) open all those files and add DB::single=1 to where I like. The whole system can crash then. I want to set breakpoint as it more secure

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

Add the following code to the line where you want to break in `file2.pl`:

```
$DB::single = 1;
```

To control the debugging automatically from that point, you need to manipulate `@DB::typeahead` array. From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html):

> You can mock TTY input to debugger by adding arbitrary commands to @DB::typeahead. For example, your .perldb file might contain:
>
> ```
>    sub afterinit { push @DB::typeahead, "b 4", "b 6"; }
> ```

This code can be either in a `BEGIN {}` block, or a special `.perldb`  config file.

Comment: i have like 100 files which are called using system. If I start doing this, it will take me more time than I can imagine. I have files in files and they all get called with system or eval

Comment: And frankly, if this is your situation, I would strongly recommend Log4Perl and Data::Dumper combination instead of interactive debugger.

Comment: can you please provide links to their resources?

Comment: @ban - http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log%3A%3ALog4perl. http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3A%3ADumper

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34261/discussion-between-ban-and-dvk)

Answer (score 0):

You pass them as you would normally:

```
perl -d ./file2.pl arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

Comment: oh, i kept putting in the file path, thanks...could you also answer the first questin