# TTY in perl, explaination and some examples

Tags: perl, debugging, terminal, tty

So I am trying run a perl debugger inside another perl debugger. I keep readin tty in perl is the solution. Can someone explain to me what tty means ( is it terminal type?) and how is it useful? This is where I read it:
http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.0/lib/perl5db.pl#$CreateTTY
The reason I am trying to use tty is because of this question I asked:
[Pass argument to perl file in debugger and set breakpoint in file executed by system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888986/pass-argument-to-perl-file-in-debugger-and-set-breakpoint-in-file-executed-by-sy)
Thanks to all the ones who answer, the more you guys tell me what it is, better the idea I get :)

Answer (score 0):

TTY (short for teletype) is basically a special input or output filehandle that connects to the terminal - namely, user input. For nitty gritty details, see:

- [Unix.SE in-depth answer on TTYs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)
- [Text Terminal HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-7.html)

---

This is what you need to know for starters (hard to say more since you didn't explain what you need to do with a TTY):

- On Unix, it typically maps to `/dev/tty` device or similar
- You can [test for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517250/how-do-i-detect-if-stdout-is-connected-to-a-tty-in-perl) using `-t` in Perl

---

As far as debugger, 2 things need to be known at least (if you intend to play with the TTY, the last paragraph is the most important). All data is near-quoted from [perldoc perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#Configurable-Options)

1. `p expr` prints to `$DB::OUT` filehandle (**NOT** `STDOUT`), which in turn is open to `/dev/tty`.

   I *think* this may be controlled by `LineInfo` option from `PERLDB_OPTS` but never played with it so not sure.
2. Can be affected by the following `$ENV{PERLDB_OPTS}` options:

   - **TTY** - The TTY to use for debugging I/O.
   - **noTTY** - If set, the debugger goes into NonStop mode and will not connect to a TTY. If interrupted (or if control goes to the debugger via explicit setting of $DB::signal or $DB::single from the Perl script), it connects to a TTY specified in the TTY option at startup, or to a tty found at runtime using the `Term::Rendezvous` module of your choice.

     This module should implement a method named new that returns an object with two methods: IN and OUT . These should return filehandles to use for debugging input and output correspondingly. The new method should inspect an argument containing the value of $ENV{PERLDB_NOTTY} at startup, or "$ENV{HOME}/.perldbtty$$" otherwise. This file is not inspected for proper ownership, so security hazards are theoretically possible.

Comment: I am trying to set a breakpoint in a file, which is called from a different file using the system command

Comment: Is there a way I can set a breakpoint in file2.pl which is being called from file1.pl using the system command or the eval command and then when I run file1.pl, I break at file2.pl???

Comment: @ban - yes. But your question was about what TTY is, not about setting breakpoints.